# AngularJS : Why ng-model value not updating in scope variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using jquery timepicker plugin and its angular directive. When I reset the the scope values from javascript then for the same time scope value not updating.

I have tried to make changes on timepicker directive file but not succeeded.

**Example:-** Select start-time 1:00AM then end-time automatically sets to 1:15AM which is updated from watch function in JS file. Now click Reset and values would be deleted or input fields would be blank. Now again select the same time 1:00AM the end-time is not filled automatically and also Reset does not work.

But that works If I change the time other than the previously selected time.

**Problem:-** After reset value in input field looks populated but that is not updating on the angular scope or model. But if I check that value through document.getElementById() function then it is displaying me that value which is inside that input field. Then why those value are not updating in angular scope.

**Requirement:-** I want to empty the fields after user click on reset. and for the second time when user select the **"same time"** the value should be updated in angular scope and model.

**Code:-**

```
 var app = angular.module('timePicker', ['ui.timepicker']);

app.controller('DemoCtrl',function($scope){
//$scope.startTime = new Date();
$scope.$watch('startTime', function (newValues, oldValues, scope) 
    {

        if( ($scope.startTime != undefined) &&  ($scope.startTime != null) && ($scope.startTime != '') )
            {
                $scope.endTime =  new Date($scope.startTime.getTime() + (15*60*1000));

                console.log($scope.startTime);
                console.log($scope.endTime);
            }   

    });

$scope.$watch('scope', function (newValues, oldValues, scope) 
    {
        console.log("Nothing here");
    });

$scope.resetTime = function()
{
  $scope.startTime = undefined;
  $scope.endTime = undefined;

}


});
```

**My Plnker:-**[Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mk3loH3kf96tsBYuZ5So?p=preview)

**Resources Used:-**

https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker whose directive in angular is on https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker.

Comment: For me it look like `scope` value is updating correctly..

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

You cant use    `$scope.$watch` for this condition, because the `$scope.$watch` is calling for whenever the `$scope.startTime` value is changed, If you select  `$scope.startTime` value is a previous value, then this below code is not called.This is why you got this problem

```
if( ($scope.startTime !== undefined) &&  ($scope.startTime !== null) && ($scope.startTime !== '') )
                {
                    $scope.endTime =  new Date($scope.startTime.getTime() + (15*60*1000));

                    console.log($scope.startTime);
                    console.log($scope.endTime);
                }
```

### Review

This issue only happen with your previous value.Once you change any other value then it's working good.

### Solution

**You need change to `ng-blur` instead of `$scope.$watch` in your first text field.**

### Fixed Demo

I have solved  your issue by using `ng-blur`. Please see this **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RFAIxj4lXFzPLp7nWpSV?p=preview)**

*also my demo have working your reset functionality* **:)** good luck

Comment: your solution is not working after I reset and use the same time which was previously selected . Please update it.

Comment: Okay, Please wait a mins, i will check and update to you

Comment: If you want to make changes inside timepicker directive file. then you can

Comment: Yes, i guess the issue coming from your directive . Will see

Comment: Actually i have a doubt, Why you using Jquery?? I think it's a conflict problem. because you have using angular js time picker and also jquery time picker.

Comment: Well the directive is not created by me. it is available on github as you can see on "Resources Used" where i have mentioned the links to resources. And Moreover the angular js time picker directive is using jquery time picker for displaying the list of time. Please see the mentioned resources.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using this code for reset

```
angular.element('#elementId').timepicker('setTime', null);
```

With this code, model value also updates with previous value.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But what if I want to do this without using #element_Id ?