# how to call function when angular watch cycle or digest cycle is completed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there any way to call custom function in angular after angular finishes all watch cycle.

**Requirement**
*I have multiple watch functions inside my controller. Now I want to execute a function only after all watch functions are executed by angular*

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do register a callback once a digest is completed.

**Using `$$postDigest`:**
`$scope.$$postDigest` fires a callback after the current `$digest` cycle completed.

However this runs only once after the next digest cycle. To make it run after each digest cycle run it along with `$watch`. This is based on the code sample [given here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5828#issuecomment-33020323)

```
var hasRegistered = false;
$scope.$watch(function() {
  if (hasRegistered) return;
  hasRegistered = true;
  $scope.$$postDigest(function() {
    hasRegistered = false;
    fn();
  });
});
```

The `$watch` can get triggered multiple times during a digest cycle so we use a flag `hasRegistered` to prevent `$$postDigest` callback to be registered multiple times.
Note: $$postDigest will not trigger another digest cycle. So any modifcation to `$scope` inside `$$postDigest` will not get reflected in the dom. `$$` means this is a private function in angularjs, so the function is not stable and may change in the future.

**Using `$timeout`:**

```
$timeout(function(){
 console.log("Running after the digest cycle");
},0,false);
```

This runs after the current digest cycle is complete.
Note: The third argument is set to false to prevent another digest cycle trigger.

Comment: can you go through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002977/why-ng-model-value-not-updating-in-scope-variable